# How to write the cloudformation subscription between Sns event topic and sqs event queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have A service where we have sns topics and in B service sqs queue event.

from B service cloud formation I need to write the cloud formation YAML file to subscription between SNS event topic and SNS event queue.

sns topic name : **sns-event-topic**

subscribed to queue name: **abcd-events**

```html
Resources:

AbcdEventQueue:
    Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    Properties:
      QueueName: "abcd-events"
AbcdEventQueuePolicy:
  Type: "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy"
    Properties:
      Queues:
        - Ref: "AbcdEventQueue"
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
            Action:
              - sqs:SendMessage
              - sqs:ReceiveMessage
              - sqs:DeleteMessage
              - sqs:GetQueueUrl
              - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
              - sqs:ListQueueTags
              - sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt AbcdEventQueue.Arn
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the SNS topic already you would create a [`AWS::SNS::Subscription`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html) resource.

It would look like the below structure

```
Subscription:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Subscription'
    Properties:
      TopicArn: !Ref TopicArn #You will need to provide the SNS Topic Arn here
      Endpoint: !GetAtt 
        - AbcdEventQueue
        - Arn
      Protocol: sqs
      RawMessageDelivery: 'true'
```

**If** the SNS topic does not share the same stack you will need to pass this into your template, this can be done either as a [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) or by using the [Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) feature to define a global value that you can use by referencing it with the [Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) intrinsic function.

Comment: in lambda 
Subscription:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
        Properties:
          EventSourceArn: !ImportValue sns-topic-arn
          FunctionName: !GetAtt Function.Arn
          Enabled: true
          BatchSize: 1

Comment: Ah I thought it was for SNS to SQS :). Have a great day :)

Comment: I have SNS service in A service, in B service i have SQS service,  From B service i need to set up a subscription between SNS event topic and SQS event queue itself, is it correct to do event mapping in B  lambda  importing it and exporting in the resourse file

Comment: The event mapping allows an event to trigger the Lambda itself. In your example an SNS trigger is able be this event source (although it would still need a subscription). If you just want SNS to SQS you can subscribe the SQS queue to the SNS topic using the template above :)

Answer (score 2):

in lambda

```
Subscription:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      EventSourceArn: !ImportValue sns-topic-arn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt Function.Arn
      Enabled: true
      BatchSize: 1
```